# Record Google Hangouts on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, audio, recording, google-hangouts

Is there any way to record an audio call on Google Hangouts on a chrome book? I know hangouts can let you record inbound calls, but I don't know if a way to record outbound calls.

Any solution, hardware or software, that would be viable?